# Anyone's using BDD in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, bdd, pester

I've found a lot of threads around this question here at stackoverflow. They are 2 years old now. So I would like to know if someone is using [scottmuc](https://github.com/scottmuc/Pester) functions to perform a BDD in powershell. It seems very powerful at first sight.

What's your opinion about? Somebody knows some other well effective BDD framework? I would like something really close to **rspec**.

**Note** I need BDD not TDD (PSUnit) suggestions/indications.

---

No many using BDD on powershell then, seen the answers :). Does it mean that BDD is not useful at all, only because powershell is just scripting? I don't think it's a valid reason.

Anyway here the list up to now:

- [Pester](https://github.com/scottmuc/Pester), much more close to something like **rspec**
- [PowerSpec](https://github.com/shishkin/PowerSpec), is seems just a few `should`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the author of Pester and happy to see that you found it! Pester was created to surround another project I did called [PowerYaml](https://github.com/scottmuc/PowerYaml) (as well as the stuff @manojlds mentioned). I wanted to refactor it, but without test coverage, I didn't feel comfortable doing that. So Pester was born, and PowerYaml got refactored. It might be a decent example to show a real world situation where it is useful.

Secondly, I've just recently published a [blog post](http://scottmuc.com/blog/development/pester-bdd-for-the-system-administrator/) that my shed some light on how to use Pester and it's workflow.

Hope this helps. If you have feature requests, please submit them to the github project.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I was also looking for a Yaml function in powershell and your intent to provide a YAML wrapper in Powershell will be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

We are using Pester in our project. It serves our purpose and we are trying to improve upon it. And yeah, the author is my colleague and wrote it for the project.

There is also PowerSpec - https://github.com/shishkin/PowerSpec ( though the description says it is aimed at TDD with Powershell )

Comment: oh well one answer :). Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge about. I'll have a look.